# Sum of squared residuals for sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm using sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression and would like to calculate standard errors for my coefficients.  As far as I can tell, sklearn does not include a function that does this, so I need to calculate them manually (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares for an example of standard errors for linear regression coefficient estimate).

I'm using the residues_ attribute of my linear regression to get the sum of squared residuals. My question is about the documentation at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html, which defines _residues as:

> residues_ : array, shape (n_targets,) or (1,) or empty. **Sum of
>   residuals**. Squared Euclidean 2-norm for each target passed during the
>   fit. If the linear regression problem is under-determined (the number
>   of linearly independent rows of the training matrix is less than its
>   number of linearly independent columns), this is an empty array. If
>   the target vector passed during the fit is 1-dimensional, this is a
>   (1,) shape array.

Is "sum of residuals" an error in the documentation?  I think it should say "sum of squared residuals". (The sum of residuals on the training data is always zero for a linear regression, if it includes a constant: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194523/why-does-the-sum-of-residuals-equal-0-from-a-graphical-perspective. Also, the following sentence in the docs says "squared Euclidean 2-norm", which is a sum of squares.) If the documentation is indeed erroneous, how can I correct it?

Edit: I can confirm my suspicion using a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

n_obs = 5
X = np.ones((n_obs, 1), dtype=float)
X[3] = 7.0
y = np.ones((n_obs, ))
y[1] = 10.0
y[3] = 9.0
model = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, n_jobs=1)

np.isclose(np.sum(np.power(y - model.predict(X=X), 2)), model.residues_)  # True
```

Comment: If you think that's an error, you can post it on their [github issues page](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues). If you are correct, then they will correct the mistake, if you are not, you still gain information about why this was written (or implemented) like this.

Comment: @VivekKumar thank you for the link, I'll do that.

Comment: Posted https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9491

Answer (score 2):

The residues were directly taken from [scipy.linalg.lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html):

> **residues** : () or (1,) or (K,) ndarray
>   Sums of residues, squared 2-norm for each column in b - a x. If rank of matrix a is < N or > M, or 'gelsy' is used, this is an empty array. If b was 1-D, this is an (1,) shape array, otherwise the shape is (K,).

So you seem to be right.

That being said, `self.residues_` is deprecated since #5452 (merged in October 2015), and will be removed in v0.19 (about to be released).
As you shown in your snippet, you can easily compute them anyway.